# extract items from json array by condition in oracle

Tags: json, oracle

I'm learning some basics of Oracle's json features but confused how to do the following.

I've got an array-rooted json in a clob, eg.

```
[{"str":"foo","num":1},{"str":"bar","num":2},{"str":"foobar","num":3}]
```

I would like to extract specific items from the array defining various conditions for the object of array, eg. when I specify a "where num != 2" condition somehow the result should be this string:

```
[{"str":"foo","num":1},{"str":"foobar","num":3}]
```

How can it be done with Oracle's bultin json functions? How can any arbitary condition be specified?

It is important that not necessarily all the keys (attribute names) are known just the one the condition stands for, so cannot enumerate all of them as json_table would require.

---

In other words, I'm looking for a way to do the very same thing with json as writing

```
select * from jsontext where num!=2
```

for a real table.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is to parse JSON, filter data, and generate JSON again.

The support of JSON format was first introduced in 12.1, so it is vital that you're on 12.1 or newer. This is how to get the version

```
select version from v$instance;
```

If you're on 12.1 (this version only, not newer) then this might help

```
select '[' || listagg('{"str": "' || jt.str || '", "num": ' || jt.num || '}', ',') within group(order by 1) || ']'
  from json_table('[{"str":"foo","num":1},{"str":"bar","num":2},{"str":"foobar","num":3}]', 
                  '$[*]' columns(str path '$.str', num path '$.num')) jt
 where num != 2;
```

In 12.2 there was another feature introduced that will reduce amout of code a bit. The json_object function will assemble columns into an json object and the json_arrayagg which is to aggregate data to a JSON array. So on 12.2 and newer the your code might look like the following

```
select json_arrayagg(json_object('str' value str, 'num' value jt.num))
  from json_table('[{"str":"foo","num":1},{"str":"bar","num":2},{"str":"foobar","num":3}]', 
                  '$[*]' columns(str path '$.str', num path '$.num')) jt
 where num != 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this way you have to enumerate all the columns you need, and a "select * " cannot be done when you don't know all the "column names".

Comment: @Feri yep it seems so. I thought you know all the element names,